# Google Scripts - Copy the text from source google sheet into the "Next Blank Row" of the destination google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to copy the text from source google sheet into the Next Blank Row of the destination google sheet by using the "destinationSheetLastRow" to identify the new row. However, it's not working. It will be great if you give me some help. My script is in below

```
//
function importRange(sourceID, sourceRange, destinationID, destinationRangeStart){

  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange)
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();

  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName(destStartRange.getSheet().getName());

  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
      destStartRange.getRow(),
      destStartRange.getColumn(),
      sourceVals.length,
      sourceVals[0].length,
    );
    
  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
//
```

Thousand thanks in advance.
Cheers Mate, Have a great day :)

Comment: there is no destinationSheetLastRow in your code! share a minimal reproducible spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

See [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastColumn()), `getLastColumn()` in Sheet and [`getNextDataCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection) in Range